# all appointment based on interval distance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently with a given `Date` and an Interval in `Day`, I can calculate all of the appointment in the future. for example if you are supposed to have an appointment each **30** day starting '**2020-09-24**', all the future appointments would be calculated like this.

```
--Source Table Creation
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DimDate

CREATE TABLE #DimDate ( id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, GregorianDate DATE)
--Sample Data
INSERT INTO #DimDate(GregorianDate)
SELECT  TOP 2000 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) , GETDATE())
FROM    sys.all_objects
```

```
--Calculation Code


;WITH cte_name --30.4375
AS ( SELECT GregorianDate,DATEADD(DAY,30,GregorianDate) next30, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GregorianDate ASC)-1) + 30) % 30 AS r
     FROM   #DimDate
     WHERE GregorianDate >='2020-09-24'
)
SELECT  *
FROM    cte_name
WHERE r=0
```

Calculation is based on residual of this part the code `((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GregorianDate ASC)-1) + 30) % 30 AS r`, if residual is 0 then we are at the next interval.

### What I am looking for

- Is there any problem not yet considered?
- Is there any other way? ( some playful way like window aggregate!)

Thank you

---

**Update**:

### Some clarification:

I have a **Date Dimension** table in which all the related Calendar *Conversion* is stored like `HijriCalendar`, `PersianCalendar` and other needed data.

That is why even though generally speaking calculating `nth` appointment using `(n * 30 (interval distance) ) + start` is faster but overall because of other data needed from Dimension it'd be the same. (Greatly appreciated)

Answer (score 3):

You can greatly simplify things as well as wildly improve performance by using something like the following...

```
DECLARE 
    @start_date date = '2020-09-24',
    @interval_in_days int = 30,
    @appt_count int = 100;

WITH 
    cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10
    cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100
    cte_Calendar (dt) AS (
        SELECT TOP (@appt_count)
            DATEADD(DAY, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval_in_days, @start_date)
        FROM
            cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b                                                    -- 10,000
        )
SELECT 
    c.dt
FROM
    cte_Calendar c;
```

You can even even create an inline table function to make life a little easier...

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_CalculateAppointmentDates
/* ===================================================================
09/22/2020, Created: Calculates all future appointment dates based 
                on a start date, specified interval and number of 
                requested appointments. 
=================================================================== */
--===== Define I/O parameters
(
    @start_date date,
    @interval_in_days int,
    @appt_count int 
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100
        cte_Calendar (dt) AS (
            SELECT TOP (@appt_count)
                DATEADD(DAY, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval_in_days, @start_date)
            FROM
                cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b                                                    -- 10,000
            )
    SELECT 
        c.dt
    FROM
        cte_Calendar c;
GO
```

Comment: Mind adding some justification as to why this performs better?

Comment: @Dannnno it doesn't involve querying any tables, doesn't create, populate or pull from any #temp tables. Doesn't create any unnecessary rows and therefore does not need to be filtered and there is no sorting required. Is that sufficient justification?

Comment: It is - can you add it to the question? Other thoughts:

1. using a variable with TOP leads to an automatic cardinality estimate of 100 rows, which may have negative consequences depending on usage (RECOMPILE hint or dynamic SQL addresses this)
2. Enabling batch mode (fake join or query hint, depending on SQL Server version) is just a hair better, but probably not enough to matter
3. Including query plans to demonstrate the improvement is always nice :) https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkfrSxdSv

Comment: 1) This is true but I've never seen it cause a problem, not even when working with millions of rows. 2) I'm not familiar with what you're doing here but the paste a plan doesn't show the creation of the #CciForBatchMode temp table (so I don't know how you have it defined). To test, I simply created it with a single BIT column and 0 rows (just to make the code execute). In my test, #CciForBatchMode was ignored and both plans were identical in shape, subtree cost and performance. That said, I am interested in learning more about the technique. Please post links if you have any available.

Comment: 3) Execution plans are a useful tool but they aren't a substitute for an actual performance test. If I'm really trying to eek out every last millisecond, I'll post execution times and IO stats before execution plans (just my own preference).

Comment: (whoops, I meant to ask if you could edit your answer to include the relevant details & justification - I think it makes this a more complete answer). Yeah, TOP hasn't been an issue for me on its own. I have seen problems when used in a subquery/view in a way that picks very different plan shapes for 100 rows vs 1M, and I wonder if it might prevent minimal logging. For CCIs, see [here](https://orderbyselectnull.com/2018/02/). Sure - time & IO stats are great too. Regardless of your preference, showing either plans or time/stats (or both!) is helpful when asserting performance improvements

Comment: thank you. updated question why your well thought answer could still be the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to query `sys.all_objects`, a simple `CTE` recursion would be enough:

```
DECLARE 
    @START_DATE DATE = '2020-09-24'
,   @END_DATE   DATE = '2026-04-26'

SET @START_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 30 , @START_DATE) 

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, @START_DATE) GregorianDate
,   DATEADD(DAY, 30, @START_DATE) next30
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, 30, GregorianDate)
,   DATEADD(DAY, 30, next30)
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 30, next30) <= @END_DATE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
OPTION(maxrecursion 0)
```

now, you can wrap this up into a `Table-valued Function` to make it reusable :

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAllAppointmentsByIntervalDistance
(   
    @START_DATE DATE
,   @END_DATE DATE
,   @DAYS INT 
)
RETURNS @TABLE TABLE(GregorianDate DATE, next30 DATE)
AS
BEGIN 

    SET @START_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, @DAYS , @START_DATE) 

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, 0 , @START_DATE) GregorianDate
    ,   DATEADD(DAY, @DAYS, @START_DATE) next30
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        DATEADD(DAY, @DAYS, GregorianDate)
    ,   DATEADD(DAY, @DAYS, next30)
      FROM CTE 
      WHERE DATEADD(DAY, @DAYS, next30) <= @END_DATE
    )
    INSERT INTO @TABLE(GregorianDate , next30)
    SELECT * FROM CTE 
    OPTION(maxrecursion 0)
    
    RETURN 
END
```

Then, reuse it :

```
DECLARE 
    @START_DATE DATE = '2020-09-24'
,   @END_DATE   DATE = '2026-04-26'
,   @DAYS       INT  = 30

SELECT * 
FROM 
    dbo.GetAllAppointmentsByIntervalDistance(@START_DATE, @END_DATE, @DAYS)
```